# Rotate images onclick with jQuery. Swap / change image with click

Tags: jquery, image, rotation, swap

I have 2 images in total. I only want the first one displayed and the 2nd one hidden.

Then when I click on the image it swaps the image around to then second image, then I click again it goes back to the first, in a loop, constantly swapping the images with every click, like 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2 and so on.

Cheers

Comment: Please share what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html:

```
<img src="URL" id="image1" />
<img src="URL" id="image2" style='display:none;'/>
```

jquery:

```
 $("#image1").click(function ( event ) {
      $(this).hide();
      $("#image2").show();
    });
 $("#image2").click(function ( event ) {
      $(this).hide();
      $("#image1").show();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this: http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/

Comment: That is not what the OP wants at all

Answer (score 0):

You may try this using jQuery's CSS function like;

```
$('.image').toggle(
function() {
    $('#img1').css({ 'display':'none' });
    $('#img2').css({ 'display':'inline' });
}, function() {
    $('#img2').css({ 'display':'none' });
    $('#img1').css({ 'display':'inline' });
});
```

***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/hnKpT/)*** is a working Live Demo